# RxJs: Chaining several groups of requests

Tags: javascript, rxjs

My data flow has the following stages:

1. Create an entity (1st request) and add several attributes (2th req).
2. After success in step 1 create several other entities (1st array of requests).
3. After success in step 2 link entity from step 1 with entities from step 2 (2nd array of requests)
4. Delete some obsolete links (3rd array of requests)

In my understanding, step 1 (forkJoin) -> step 2 (switchMap + forkJoin) -> step 3 + step 4 (?)

**Note: I don't need result data of each request(s) just success status**.

At the moment, I have working code for steps 1 and 2. And I don't know how or where to implement step 3 and 4 after success in step 2

```
forkJoin(
    createEntity()    // step 1 - 1st req
    saveAttributes()  // step 1 - 2nd req
).pipe(
    switchMap(data =>  forkJoin(createRelatedAssets()))   // step 2 - 1st array of req-s
).subscribe(
    ok => {
        console.log('Success');
    },
    error => onError(error, 'API error')
);
```

Comment: Is there any dependence between step 4 and any of the earlier steps? If not it seems like you could include those requests in the `forkJoin` for the related assets.

Comment: @Jack A. You are right, I could. Step 4 depends only on step 1. According to `forkJoin` documentation, it accepts either array of observers, or observers passed directly. So, as I understand, before calling 2nd `forkJoin` I need manually merge array of `createRelatedAssets` and array of `deleteObsoleLinks` (step 4) ?

Comment: You could `forkJoin([...createRelatedAssets(), ...deleteObsoleteLinks()])`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem right, I would try something along these lines

```
forkJoin(
    createEntity()    // step 1 - 1st req
    saveAttributes()  // step 1 - 2nd req
).pipe(
    switchMap(data_1 =>  forkJoin(createRelatedAssets().pipe(
      // when the above forkJoin emits, link the data emitted by the
      // the first forkJoin (data_1 is an array of 2 values, i.e. the values
      // emitted by createEntity() and saveAttributes()) with the data emitted
      // by the second forkJoin
      map(data_2 => linkEntities(data_1, data_2))
    )),
    // when the above forkJoin emits, launch the execution of the new
    // array of requests with forkJoin
    switchMap(linkedData =>  forkJoin(createStep3Requests(linkedData).pipe(
      // since you need the result of step 1 in step 4, you can embed data_1
      // (the data emitted by step 1) within the object linkedData and return
      // linkedData
      map(() => linkedData)
    )),
    // now you can perform step 4
    switchMap(linkedData => doStep4(linkedData))
)   
).subscribe(
    ok => {
        console.log('Success');
    },
    error => onError(error, 'API error')
);
```

Comment: I don't need result data at all, just that each step was succeeded. Steps should follow each other, except 3 and 4 that may execute in parallel but only after steps 1 and 2.